# Need to use Solr dismax handler but i have no q parameter???

Tags: search, lucene, search-engine, solr

Hi 
   i am trying to make a solr Query using dismax handler but i have no q parameters because i have to match directly on fields..

```
hl.fragsize=200&mm=1&facet=on&facet.mincount=1&qf=text+&wt=json&hl=true&rows=50&fl=*+score&start=0&q=*:*&fq=jSFunT:("Fresher"+OR+"Developer+/+Programmer+/+Coder")&fq=jNMinEx:[2+TO+*]&fq=jNMaxEx:[2+TO+5]&fq=jNMinSal:[-1+TO+*]&fq=jNMaxSal:[-1+TO+-1]&bq=jSFunT:("Developer+/+Programmer+/+Coder")^1&bq=jSkill:(HTML)^2&bq=jCID:(41449)^8&bq=jJT:(Developer+)^8&bq=jLoc:(Mumbai-Thane+)^4&bq=jINDT:("IT(Software,+Dotcom,+Infra.Mgmt.%26+UI+Design)")^1

OR you can better understand it from below..   

&mm=1
&qf=text

&wt=json

&hl=true

&rows=50

&fl=*+score

&start=0

&q=*:*

&fq=jSFunT:("Fresher"+OR+"Developer+/+Programmer+/+Coder")

&fq=jNMinEx:[2+TO+*]

&fq=jNMaxEx:[2+TO+5]

&fq=jNMinSal:[-1+TO+*]

&fq=jNMaxSal:[-1+TO+-1]

&bq=jSFunT:("Developer+/+Programmer+/+Coder")^1

&bq=jSkill:(HTML)^2

&bq=jCID:(41449)^8

&bq=jJT:(Java Developer)^8

&bq=jLoc:(Mumbai-Thane)^4

&bq=jINDT:("IT(Software,+Dotcom,+Infra.Mgmt.%26+UI+Design)")^1
```

Here all the "bq" will not work because the qt=dismax is not supplied if i use that then the whole query will fail

can i any one help me out i will be very thankful for this kindness

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [q.alt parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#q.alt), which lets you specify a fall back query:

```
q.alt=*:*
```

If you replace your q parameter with that one, dismax should play just fine.

Comment: Johansson.that will not work form me bcz you can use q.alt=*:* to denote that all documents should be returned when no query is specified...here the case is different

Comment: If you provide q.alt, the bq and fq parameters from your example, and omit the q parameter, you should land at the result list you seem to ask for.